# How to pass the output of a script as an argument to a ssh command?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I have a script that shows all the instances on AWS that I'm running:

```
$/home/scripts/show_instances.sh
i-f66d2de0  running 10.148.17.40
i-fxxdbbe0  running 10.148.20.60
(...)
```

What I'd like to do is to take the first IP, pipe to ssh and connect to the server automatically. I tried this:

```
$/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}' | xargs ssh
```

But is not working: it connects to the server but after the first command that I type (i.e. ls), the terminal just seems to be waiting for something and nothing happens (I'm on mac connecting to Unix), so I have to exit the instance with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Some suggestions?

Comment: Not sure that `xargs` is buying you anything in this case. If your headline is really your Q, then `ssh $(..../show_instances.sh | awk 'NR==1{print $3}') ..other ssh stuff ...` (using cmd-substitution `$(...)`) should solve your problem. (don't need tail). Otherwise it seems that your Q may be about "how do I use `xargs`). Good luck.

Comment: Generally you can use backticks (or `$( )` ) for obtaining this (I can't show you how backticks work because they are used for formatting purposes on StackOverflow website).

Comment: Wow! Genius! It's working now! I did like this:

    ssh `/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`

Thank you!

Comment: Explaining better, both ways work, like you said.

    ssh (backticks)/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'(backticks)

or using $(..)

    ssh "$(/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')"

Thank you!

Comment: Join the early 90's and use `$(... cmds sub )` ;-) .. Backticks are your backup, if you get stuck using an ancient system that doesn't support `$(..)`. Also, read about the `awk` internal variable `NR`, you don't need `tail` for this case. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a command substitution, and run one go of `awk` in that to get the desired IP from first line, and then do `ssh`:

```
ssh "$(/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | awk 'NR==1{print $NF; exit}')"
```

If you want to stick to the piping, and `xargs` one, then allocating pseudo TTY (`-t`) should let you in and run interactively:

```
/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | awk 'NR==1{print $NF; exit}' | xargs ssh -tt
```

---

For last line, do:

```
ssh "$(/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | awk 'END{print $NF}')"
/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | awk 'END{print $NF}' | xargs ssh -tt
```

Comment: Worked! I did like this:

    ssh "$(/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')"

Thank you!

Comment: @ArthurAccioly Check my edits. You don't need `tail`, you can do this with `awk` alone.

Comment: Wow! Even better! Like this right? 

ssh "$(/home/scripts/show_instances.sh | awk 'END{print $NF}')"

I'm not very good on awk. Why NF gets exactly the IP?

btw, the second option with ssh -tt didn't work and I had the same issue of terminal waiting for something after any command, like "ls". But, anyway, I'm very happy with the command.

Comment: @ArthurAccioly `NF` gets us the number of fields, and `$NF` gets the last field's value expectedly.